# Cannot delete folder with space in name in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I don't know how this happened but I have a folder on my D: drive which I cannot delete. The error message is something like this (translated from German):

> Element not found
>   The Element is no longer in D:\Downloads\
>   Check the Elements location and repeat the process

The folder's name is `Yuki` (there is a space behind the i) I don't know how the space got there but it seems to be there.
The folder is empty (no hidden elements)

I cannot delete the folder, however I can create a folder inside the folder if I `right-click > new` I have only one option available which is folder (labeled with an admin-icon (I guess its called that, the blue/yellow shield)
If, for example, I create the folder `test` in `Yuki` I am able to delete the folder `test` and I am able to create everything I normally can folder, text-doc and so on (in the folder `test`)

I already tried to:

- Remove the folder normally `right click > delete` (triggers above error)
- Remove the folder with Cmd (System cannot find the file specified)
- Remove the folder with "Everything" (nothing happens)
- Remove the folder with Cmd in safe-boot (System cannot find the file specified)

Now I am out of ideas and hope anyone here could help me (I am sorry if my English is unintelligible I will try to clarify everything that comes up.

Edit1:
I forgot to mention: Yes I tried renaming the folder first I tried to just get rid of the space and got this error message

> the source and destination file names are the same

If I try to rename it like `Yukirename` or even `Yuki rename` I get the same error message when trying to delete the file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need to boot into Linux; you can use the special `\\?\` syntax to remove this directory (if it's empty) from the command prompt:

```
rd "\\?\D:\Downloads\Yuki "
```

Alternatively, if you run `dir /x` from the directory above the problematic one, you will also see its short name that you can use to get rid of it. If the short name turns out to be `YUKI~1`, this will also remove it:

```
rd YUKI~1
```

If you don't want to remove it right away (e.g. if it's not empty), you can rename it to make it more manageable:

```
ren YUKI~1 Yuki
```

Comment: Thank you the special syntax worked I tried dir /x before but it wouldnt output the 8.3filename. May I ask what this special syntax does exactly?

Comment: It tells the Windows API functions to bypass a lot of the checking that they normally do. For example, you can use this to work with very long paths, or to add dots at the end of a file or directory name. [This MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) has more information.

Comment: first solution worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

You could also delete the offending folder by issuing the following command:

```
RD "Yuki \"
```

The double quotes are obvious but the trailing backslash is key here.

How can this Windows quirk not have been resolved yet?

Comment: It worked for me on Windows 7. On the other hand,  this issue is very easy to reproduce using "Double commander", as this app allows to create a folder with a space at the end (though same app cannot remove a folder with a space at the end)

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10, thanks!